# Spring's @Condtional annotation with Java 8

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-annotations, spring-java-config

I was using `@Conditional` annotation and had to provide implementation of `matches()` of `Condition` interface. Since the `Condition` is a `FunctionalInterface`, how can I use Java 8 lambda to provide implementation **in annotation** rather than providing implementation.

```
@Conditional(value = MyCondition.class)

class MyCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return ifMatches;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Lambdas are instances of classes and `@Conditional` needs the class itself.

The lambda

```
Function<String, String> capitalize = text -> text.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Is functionally identical to

```
Function<String, String> capitalize = new Function<String, String>() {
    public String apply(String text) {
        return Function<String, String> capitalize = text -> text.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
};
```

Both are *instances* of anonymous classes and not the anonymous class itself. There is no way to actually access anonymous classes (outside of reflection, but you can't use reflection in annotations).

Passing a a lambda where a class is expected would be like passing a String where a class is expected. I.e. something like this:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    Class<?> value();
}

@MyAnnotation("this is a string")
public class MyClass {
}
```

which you wouldn't expect to work.

Comment: is there any standard way for this kinda situation where lambda cannot work?

Comment: Definitely, lambdas work where the target type is an instance of a functional interface - e.g. `void doSomething(Function<Integer, String> function)` - but not where the target type is a class - e.g. `void doSomething(Class<? extends Function> functionClass)`